# How can I efficiently determine up front all the methods called by my .NET Framework library that are NOT truly implemented in .NET Standard 2.0/2.1?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I efficiently determine up front (as in, before waiting for the runtime errors to pour in; ideally before doing the code conversion) all the methods called by my .NET Framework library that are NOT actually implemented in .NET Standard 2.0/2.1?  The Portability Analyzer only tells you if the method is not there at all (won't compile); the compiler only tells you what won't compile; but neither will tell you the methods whose functionality has been gutted such that it will produce runtime errors if your code ever hits it.  I'd rather not leave around such time bombs for my users to find... and while I'd like to think my unit tests and automated UI tests will cover 100% of my code, most of us haven't quite achieved that.

So, I am hoping someone is aware of an analyzer that highlights things that are there but are NOT implemented?... or even has a simple list of methods that are there, but don't work?...  Or any other tool/approach for finding those up front?

(Just as evidence of the need... a couple months ago I used Portability Analyzer to tell me what I needed to fix to convert my .NET Framework libs to .NET Standard 2.0... not too bad... so, I did it.  Compiler found a few other issues based on the specific arg lists.  Okay, fixed those.  All compiled.  All tests ran just fine.  So, I thought that I was good.  So, then a month ago I started converting our app to .NET 5, building on the newly-converted .NET Standard 2.0 libs.  But today I got "lucky" and discovered that, although it compiles just fine, it will never actually work... Thread.Abort doesn't do what it is supposed to (i.e., inject a ThreadAbortException into the target Thread), it instead does nothing to that thread, and worse throws a PlatformNotSupportedException on the calling thread.  Egad.  Glad I found that before my customers did.  But I wonder how many other methods are similarly compiling fine under .NET Standard 2.0, but have been similarly gutted such that they won't actually function properly.  It would have been nice if the Portability Analyzer had told me that... or any other tool/approach that might be out there.)

Comment: [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, quaabaam's comment/link was a better overview than I had found before as it includes the two things I have been missing:

This list of such not-really-supported methods:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/unsupported-apis

and mention of a "Platform Compatibility Analyzer" which is different from the ".NET Portability Analyzer".  To enable that in your .NET Standard x.x projects (or .NET Framework projects that you're considering converting), then add a *.editorconfig* file to your project with this line:

```
dotnet_code_quality.enable_platform_analyzer_on_pre_net5_target=true
```

Thanks quaabaam!!  I have dozens of articles/posts/MS-docs open on doing the conversion, and none of them mention that!